# 404 response when creating a course with the API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am attempting to create a course with the API, and no matter how I tweak what I am sending I keep getting back the same 404 error. I am posting the following to /d2l/api/lp/1.4/courses/ in our test instance.

```
{
   "Name":"STLR Course-112",
   "Code":"STLR.112.201420",
   "Path":"",
   "CourseTemplateId":22462,
   "SemesterId":22460,
   "StartDate":"2014-05-07T12:00:00.000Z",
   "EndDate":"2014-05-07T13:00:00.000Z",
   "LocaleId":null,
   "ForceLocale":false,
   "ShowAddressBook":false
}
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that my problem might be that I'm using the wrong content type for my post, should it be application/json or text/json?

Comment: Scratch that last idea, just tried both application/json and text/json, still getting the 404.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm with a test instance here that this API works with data almost identical to the block you provide here. POSTing a body like this (white space added for clarity):

```
{"CourseTemplateId": 8082, 
 "LocaleId": null, 
 "Code": "STLR.112.201420", 
 "Name": "STLR Course-112", 
 "Path": "", 
 "ShowAddressBook": false, 
 "EndDate": "2014-05-07T13:00:00.000Z", 
 "StartDate": "2014-05-07T12:00:00.000Z", 
 "ForceLocale": false, 
 "SemesterId": 6984}
```

Gets me a 200 with a response like this (white space added for clarity):

```
{"Identifier":"114119",
 "Name":"STLR Course-112",
 "Code":"STLR.112.201420",
 "IsActive":true,
 "Path":"/content/enforced/114119-STLR.112.201420/",
 "StartDate":"2014-05-07T12:00:00.000Z",
 "EndDate":"2014-05-07T13:00:00.000Z",
 "CourseTemplate":{"Identifier":"8082",
                   "Name":"ExtensibilityTemplate",
                   "Code":"EXT-TMPL"},
 "Semester":{"Identifier":"6984",
             "Name":"Fall 2011",
             "Code":"FA2011"},
 "Department":{"Identifier":"8081",
               "Name":"Extensibility",
               "Code":"EXT"}
}
```

It appears to me that the only differences between my input block and yours are the IDs provided for course template and semester, so that I could hook the new course into *my* local test instance instead of the IDs for those orgunits in yours. Otherwise, it appears the input properties are identical.

Some things you could look at:

- Ensure you're using the right Org Unit Id values for your course template and your semester
- Ensure that your LMS is configured to enforce content paths for new org units: this should then provoke the LMS to auto-create the path for you when you create a course offering; if you don't have content path enforcement on, then you might have to instead specify a valid content path for your course offering on create, and passing in an empty string probably won't be a valid path, and thus you might get a 404 back because the API service handler "can't find the content path" you've specified.

Is there a particular message that comes back with the 404?

Comment: The org unit id values I am using for my course and semester are being looked up using the /d2l/api/lp/1.4/orgstructure/ route and I am getting valid OrgUnitProperties for them so they should map up to existing org units in D2L. I think that enforce content paths is on since one was created for me when I created the course template I am using (not using the API), but I have sent an email to my D2L admin to double check that.

Regarding messages from the API, all I am getting in the content of my response (unless I am confused about something) is "Bad Request".

Comment: Hmmm. If you're error message coming back is 'Bad Request', that would suggest that the actual HTTP return code is a 403, and not a 404... as it seems the system's call does work (on our test machine) and your data seems fine (on our test machine), this sounds more like a debugging session and not a straightforward question and answer. I'd suggest you pursue this on the Valence user forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/valenceusers) to help work through this.

Comment: It's possible that you're getting a 404 from higher up the stack than the API service handler: for example, if for some reason your call can't get bound to the service handler in the first place (you're not actually making a POST, or your LMS doesn't support v1.4 although you specify that in your route, or something else that's causing a "resource not there" type error from the routing layer). Can you grab a packet trace using Fiddler or something and pursue this over on the user forum; then we could come back with an answer here once it's been root-caused?

Comment: Whoops, I was trying some different options for how I was formatting my dates and didn't notice that I was getting a different response code. Anyway, I will follow up on this in the Google Group user forum on Monday.

Comment: I was able to get the course creation to work correctly once I set the SemesterId parameter to null.

Comment: The SemesterId should be the org unit ID for a Semester type org unit. If you provide it with an Id for an org unit that is not a semester, this could perhaps result in a "Bad Request" (as your provided org unit would not validate as a valid Semester-type).